# Räte-Ideen: looking for a translation

Tags: translation, german-to-english, expression

Wie würden Sie "Räte-Ideen" verstehen/übersetzen?

> das konnte nur in den Räte-Ideen erscheinen

I understand, something such as, "it could only appear in simplistic classwork essays", or it is wishful thinking, an unrealistic promise.

Example (from [here](https://jungle.world/artikel/2000/25/das-wundersame-ueberleben-der-unmittelbaren-subjekte)):

> Dass bei ihrer gesellschaftlichen Reproduktion »die Menschen (...) freiwillig (und) gemeinsam über den Inhalt ebenso wie über die Vorgehensweise beraten und beschließen«, bezeichnet Kurz im »Schwarzbuch« für eine emanzipatorische Praxis als entscheidendes »**Kriterium, das nur in den Räte-Ideen kurz aufscheinen konnte**, aber an der mangelnden Kritik der 'abstrakten Arbeit' und der daraus entspringenden kapitalistischen Verkehrsformen gescheitert war«.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Gegen Ende des Ersten Weltkriegs wurde in der sogenannten [Novemberrevolution](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novemberrevolution) von 1918 Kaiser Wilhelm II. gestürzt. Deutschland war jetzt keine Monarchie mehr - aber was stattdessen? In dieser Zeit gab es viele konkurrierende Ideen, wie es in Deutschland politisch und gesellschaftlich weitergehen sollte. Durchgesetzt hat sich am Ende die Idee der [parlamentarischen Demokratie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parlamentarisches_Regierungssystem) (zumindest bis 1933, aber das ist ein Thema für sich).

Unter den anderen Ideen, die ebenfalls propagiert und oft in kleinerem Maßstab ausprobiert wurden, ist die wohl wichtigste die [Räterepublik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A4terepublik).

Hier ist nicht der Platz, die genauen Unterschiede zwischen einem parlamentarischen System und einem Rätesystem aufzuschlüsseln. Ein wichtiger Unterschied ist jedoch, dass eine parlamentarische Demokratie auf dem [freien Mandat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freies_Mandat) basiert: Ein gewählter Abgeordneter ist nur seinem Gewissen gegenüber verantwortlich, er bekommt keine "Aufträge" von seinen Wählern, an die er sich halten müsste. In einem Rätesystem gibt es ein [imperatives Mandat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperatives_Mandat): Der Abgeordnete bekommt konkrete inhaltliche Vorgaben, an die er sich halten muss.

Seither gab es bei verschiedenen Gelegenheiten Diskussionen darüber, wie das politische und gesellschaftliche Leben organisiert sein sollte, zum Beispiel rund um das Jahr 1968. Auch Ideen aus dem Umfeld des Rätesystems kamen dabei wieder auf. Das dürften die "Räte-Ideen" sein, um die es in der Frage geht:

> [ein] Kriterium, das nur in den Räte-Ideen kurz aufscheinen konnte (...)

---

Close to the end of the First World War the German Emperor Wilhelm II got toppled in the [November Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Revolution_of_1918%E2%80%931919). Now, Germany wasn't a monarchy anymore — but what should take its place? In this period there were a lot of competing ideas on how politics and society in German should be organized. In the end, the [parliamentary system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_system) took hold (at least until 1933, but that's a topic in itself).

Among the other ideas that were also propagated or even tried on a local or regional basis, probably the most important was the idea of a [Räterepublik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_republic_(system_of_government)). This system is often called a "soviet republic", but it's not necessarily connected to the Soviet Union.

This isn't the place to dive deep into the exact differences between a parliamentary system and a Räte system. One important difference is that in a parliamentary system a member of parliament would have a [free mandate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandate_(politics)), meaning the delegate isn't bound to any wishes or orders from their constituents. In a Räte system on the other hand the delegate would have an [imperative mandate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mandate), meaning the constituents could bind their delegate to specific wishes, policies, a specific voting behaviour etc.

Since 1918, the political and societal organisation of Germany has been discussed at multiple occasions and on many levels, among them the years around 1968. In those discussions, some ideas out of the context of the Räte system were brought to the table again. Those are presumably the "Räte-Ideen", that the question talks about:

> [ein] Kriterium, das nur in den Räte-Ideen kurz aufscheinen konnte (...)

Comment: Verstehe ich die Antwort richtig, dass sie den passenden Kontext der Räte-Ideen setzt, damit nun ein Englisch-Muttersprachler hergehen kann, um ein passendes historisches englisches Beispiel finden kann? Also dass erstmal "Begriff verstehen", und noch nicht "Begriff übersetzen"?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Mir ist keine etablierte Übersetzung bekannt, die nicht zumindest missverständlich für den Laien wäre - nicht zuletzt, weil der englische Begriff "sovjet" immer noch ein nennenswertes Triggerpotential hat (wie beerdigt man einen politischen Vorschlag in den USA? Man nennt ihn "socialist"). Außerdem, setzt nicht jede Übersetzung voraus, dass man den Ursprungstext oder -begriff zumindest in groben Zügen verstanden hat? Deshalb erscheint es mir sinnvoller, den Begriff "Räte-Idee" zu erklären als "nur" einen Übersetzungsversuch zu liefern.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm The problem is that there is no satisfactory translation into English. For the *Räte-concept* one normally one finds explanations like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_republic_(system_of_government)) which explicitly use the word "Soviet" and are therefore misleading because they identify it, at least linguistically,  with the political system of the former USSR.  In the above wiki-article one learns "Although the term is usually associated with Soviet member-states, it was not initially used to represent the political organisation of the Soviet Union,

Comment: but merely a form of democracy." However, the title "Soviet republic (system of government)" certainly determines the tenor. In my opinion the spirit of "Räte-Ideen" is reflected in the English [grassroots movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassroots) (see Takkat's answer), although it is not a precise equivalent.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, as soon as the meaning is sufficiently explained, looking for the best English translation is not a question about the German language anymore.

Comment: Ich stimme Euch allen zu, dass es weder eine etablierte noch einfach so vorurteilsfreie/sinnvolle Übersetzung gibt. Ich unterstütze daher vollständig, ein wenig auszuholen, was das Wort im Deutschen überhaupt bedeutet. Meine Frage kommt daher, weil derdiedas OP von "verstehen/übersetzen" geschrieben hat. Und ich keinen Übersetzungsversuch entdeckt hatte.

Comment: The German word "Rat" in its politcal sense is still alive in "Betriebsrat" and therefore I guess that many Germans have an imagination what the "Räte-Idee" is. This concept is not known in the USA, and this makes  it difficult to find a single word in (American) English.

Comment: @PaulFrost I haven't looked into the Räte system that deeply, but as far as I understand the imperative mandate is key. A "Betriebsrat" (or a "Stadtrat" and so on) doesn't have an imperative mandate, but a free mandate. So that might be a wrong track as well.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck In the "legal sense" you may be right (imperative mandate), but I think the **idea** of a "Rat" is a much broader concept which is well-known in Germany. See [here](http://www.rechtslexikon.net/d/r%C3%A4tesystem/r%C3%A4tesystem.htm). In contemporary German it is therefore not adequate to identfy it with the Russian "Soviet" - although the original intention for using it may have been precisely that.

Comment: _In contemporary German it is therefore not adequate to identfy it with the Russian "Soviet"_ On the contrary. Räte were 'Arbeiterräte' created and delegated by the workers. Soviets otoh were controlled by the communist party elite. So they are almost the opposite! Many esp. in the English speaking world never get the difference between socialism and communism, obvisously hard when living in generations of capitalist slander.

Answer (score 9):

Compounding *Räte* and *Idee* in the given context refers to the [**idea of councils**](https://www.kas.de/de/web/linksextremismus/was-sind-raete-als-ergaenzungen-des-parlaments-) as a form of "grassroots democracy". After the Russian Revolution such councils formed the governmental structure in Russia leading to the term [Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union) where *sovjet* is Russian (сове́т) for council (*in German:* **Rat**).

In the given context I would therefore refer to history and translate it as:

> Soviet idea *or* Soviet ideology

Comment: I'd rather go with your first translation "idea of councils", or maybe "concept of councils", since the term "Soviet anything" is not neutral.

Comment: @Erik The term to translate isn't neutral and so is the translation. It is the context of the time (roughly 100 years ago) which explains it - even if the term by itself appears to be neutral, it wasn't.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: thank you for this comment. It is obvious that neither the (historical!) term nor it's use in the given context was neutral.

Answer (score 1):

In the German language, the term `Räte-Ideen` ultimately refers to the politics of the [`Reichsrätekongress`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichsr%C3%A4tekongress) (also see [Richard Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_M%C3%BCller_(socialist)) and the [KPD](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kommunistische_Partei_Deutschlands) for some more context). The `Räterepublik` was indeed formed with Soviet Russia as the model - so the above translation "Soviet idea or Soviet ideology" generally can be applied. We even once had a [Bavarian Soviet Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_Soviet_Republic), even if it was short-lived (Established 6 April 1919 / Disestablished 3 May 1919).

It could also be more generally translated as: "the ideas/politics of a council". It may also depend if someone wrote in favor of these ideologies whether or not, because one could also interpret it even more derogatory as "the BS they came up with", expressed in a newspaper-printable way (as not everybody was amazed of Soviet ideology). Similar to modern politics - which are barely neutral, but quite biased. One can assume, that `Räte-Ideen` may have referred to left-wing ideology.

Comment: _formed with Soviet Russia as the model_ Only in the delusional sense that many had of the soviets. Today it should be understood that they, from the beginning, were not repesenting the working class as they claimed but the communist party elite.